# What is the memory footprint of a phonegap application compared to its native counterpart?

Tags: memory-management, mobile, cordova

I am evaluating pros and cons of Phonegap (Cordova) versus its native application.  Does anyone have any baseline information and then include features and functions?

Comment: Why the down vote and recommendation to close?  I found these questions all over SO before I posted?!?

Answer (score 1):

Here are the main pros and cons of using Cordova / Phonegap:

**The pros of Cordova / Phonegap:**

1. You just need HTML5/CSS/Javascript skills and you do not require any specific knowledge of Objective-C, which makes things simpler for creating your applications.
2. You have single code base for all platforms (iOS, Android, Windows 7, mobile web), which means that you can deploy your applications for several platforms very quickly!
3. Rapid testing and deployment (up until you Phonegap it, at which point you're subject to App Store review conditions, etc)
4. With Phonegap, you can still take advantage of distribution and integrated payment via the App Store or Android Market

**The cons of Cordova / Phonegap:**

1. Poor performance, especially if your applications are graphically intense, (eg: like games). You can implement caching or leverage some 3rd party solutions (i.e. Sibblingz) for native graphics acceleration; but for the most part, native applications are much faster/smoother than mobile web apps
2. Lack of pre-built UI widgets, transitions, standard controls, etc. Your development time can take longer, especially if you want polished-looking applications with a native look and feel. You can try using Sencha Touch, JQuery Mobile, plugins, or similar tools with pre-built UI elements, but you'll probably still need to spend a good amount of time styling the applications to look native.

---

So, in my opinion, if you want to include "full features" (like good performances, fast app, access to native components, etc) for your application, you'd better create a native application.

Phonegap / Cordova is much more like a convenient tool for creating "web like applications" very quickly, and in an easier way (especially if you already know about HTML/Javascript/CSS, for instance).
I think you would use Phonegap / Cordova if you want an application which is not too sophisticated, you want to deploy your app quite quickly, and / or you're feeling comfortable with HTML/javascript/CSS but not with Objective-C.

---

Hope these answers help.

Comment: This is *VERY* helpful, although I am still looking for the memory footprint so I can decide if it needs to be in the CONS list or if it is negligible.  You provide a nice contrast and it is consistent with my analysis.  I did not know about the pre-built widgets and I found JCQuery; I will look for the JQuery Mobile.

Comment: Good choice for jQuery Mobile :P! Personally I like it because it is packed up with jQuery and it's supported by several platforms (I think jQuery Mobile is the only one supporting the greatest number of platforms... I'll have to check this :) )